# Run crontab job with P4

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron, perforce

I have a shell script which in turn calls a python script. But before the python script runs I am setting up the environment variables in order to have the right P4 configurations.

```
shell: /home/ag/ump_prod/run.sh
python script: /home/ag/ump_prod/cron.py
Environment conf: /home/ag/ump_prod/env.conf
```

The python script executes command line P4 commands via the subprocess module. 
Here is the code for the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
. /home/ag/ump_prod/env.conf
python /home/ag/ump_prod/cron.py
```

env.conf

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
export USER=ag
export MAIL=/var/mail/ag
export HOME=/home/ag
export LOGNAME=ag
export P4CONFIG=/home/ag/ump_prod/.perforce
```

The perforce config /home/ag/ump_prod/.perforce :

```
P4CLIENT=ag_ump
P4EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
P4PORT=rsh:ssh -2 -q -a -x -l p4server p4.****.com /bin/true
P4USER=ag
```

Manually running the shell script executes it without any issues.
However, when I run it via cronjob it complains that it cannot connect to the server.

Error Message:

```
['TCP receive failed.\n', 'read: socket stdio: Connection reset by peer\n', 'Perforce client error:\n', '\tTCP receive failed.\n', '\tread: socket stdio: Connection reset by peer\n']
```

Please let me know where I could be going wrong in setting the environment variables for P4 configs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I needed to start the ssh-agent dynamically for the cronjob as well. It is just like how you login for the first time and start the ssh-agent. We need to tell cronjob too to include eval `ssh-agent`